# How do I change an icon in a menu, after the menu has already been created?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Hi I'm new to Android Development, and so far learning has been going quite well, but I've hit a snag with something that is probably dead simple.

I've set up GCM with my app, it works fine. I have an icon in my android action bar that represents a notification. What I would like to do is change this icon, upon generating a notification in the app.

This is the first time I've ever asked a question on here, so please except my apologies if the question is not detailed enough or a duplicate, I've looked at other answers, but could not seem to find an exact match for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change actionbar menu item by this way. here menu is o`nCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`.

```
menu.getItem(5 here 5 is menu number).setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_important));
```

Thanks

Comment: Okay thank you, what if I wanted to change the menu item from another class? My main activity is called Dashboard and I have a separate class that handles the notifications. I would like to change the menu item from here. I've just gotten a book for Java/Android development, so sorry if I seem dim lol!

Comment: Put the data in sharePreference and other store then check  this data in Dashboard and change the icon.

Comment: One more question if thats okay? I've got this all working now, but I want to call invalidateOptionsMenu() from my other class, so how would I do this. Everything I've tried has caused NullException errors. Can you recommend any other good training sources too? Sorry for this other question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and call `invalidateOptionsMenu`